# Password protect whole staging site. Redirect to original page not working

Tags: redirect, password, login

I'm trying to password protect a staging site. So I've put a {% requireLogin %} at the top of my _layout.html inside of a conditional tag. It's working except the redirect after login always goes to the dashboard instead of the original page. What am I doing wrong?

I'm aware of the possibility of using htaccess protection, but I think doing it the "Craft way" is nicer.

Comment: What version of Craft are you using (Personal Client or Pro)? Is your login form on the front end? Or are you using the standard /admin control panel login?

Comment: Be sure you're testing with a user account that doesn't have CP access as well.

Comment: I'm using the Pro-Version and the standard /admin login.

So it's not supposed to work for users with CP access as well? Would be nice if that was configurable.

Comment: Are you visiting the site without "www" and have "www" as part of your siteUrl in settings or vice versa? I once had a redirect like you are describing and think that was the cause.

Answer (score 2):

`{% requireLogin %}` is intended for use with your own login form on the frontend rather than the standard /admin one. From the docs for [loginPath](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#loginPath):

> [The URI Craft should use for user login on the front-end.](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#loginPath)

Which means you create your own frontend login form, and set that as the `loginPath`. As you don't have that, it's defaulting to the default login instead, which redirects users to the admin dashboard instead of the page they were on.

Comment: Clive, I think you can remove a ? or two :-)